# How to Change view's from a UIVeiwController to a Scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I Have a UIViewController That I need and I would like it to stay a UIView Controller. but I have a back button that takes you to an Scene that's not working. i just simply need to get to the SKcene any way possible. Thanks

Code:

```
  @IBAction func BackButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var scene = GameScene()
    let sKView = self.view! as! SKView
    sKView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.size = sKView.bounds.size
    let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.45)
    sKView.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)

}
```

}
this function is current giving me this Error below

```
  Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x1991fa530) to 'SKView' (0x198f5f560).
```

My Game Scene is my SkScene and my UIViewController that is attached to the storyboard view is called SoundboardController

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: OK I'm trying to go from a UIViewController to a SKcene like as you would using a segue.